# How to install SSL ceritificate from Let's Encrypt for Bot deployment

Tags: botframework, lets-encrypt

How to install SSL certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for Bot deployment in Windows 8.1 for Visual Studio 2015.
Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so you can learn what types of questions are accepted here, how to write questions, and how to use this site effectively

Answer (score 0):

You get issues, as certificate of Let's Encrypt is not allowed yet in Bot Framework.
Bot Framework [allows](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/authentication/#authentication-technologies) only X.509v3 certificates and
the certificate must [chain](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1328) to a root certificate authority trusted by Microsoft. The latest list of these CAs is available [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31634.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-participants.aspx#Latest).